# Tokenizing First Name and Last Name as one word

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition, spacy

> > Input: Barack Obama is the President
> >
> > (Desire) Output: Who is the President?

the problem is although SpaCy recognize Barack Obama as one person, but when tokenizing the text in the earlier stage, Barack Obama had been separated into two words, ie: "Barack" and "Obama"

attached is my sample code:

```
import spacy
from nltk import word_tokenize


nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
text = 'Barack Obama is the President'
BreakText = word_tokenize(text)
document = nlp(text)

person = []
for ent in document.ents:
    if ent.label_ == 'PERSON':
        person.append(ent)

k = person[0]
j = BreakText.index(str(k))
BreakText[j] = 'Who'
Final = " ".join(BreakText)
print(Final + "?")
```

or is there another way around to get my desire output?

> > UPDATE: this works!

```
k = person[0]
o = text.replace(str(k), 'Who')
print(o + "?")
```

Comment: Barak and Obama are two different words so perhaps tokenizing by words isn't what you want? It seems like this would be making your tokens phrases.

Answer (score 0):

Spacy will give you the full text of the entity with `ent.text`.

Answer (score -1):

You are describing named entity recognition (NER), rather than tokenization.

Chapter 7 in the nltk docs describes how NER takes a few steps forward from tokenization, to part of speech tagging, to entity recognition.

http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html

```
nltk.ne_chunk()
```

Is most likely the functionality you are interested in.